# boost::filesystem::create_directory: Illegal byte sequenc

Tags: c++, macos, boost, encoding

I'm trying to use the boost::filesystem library to create a directory in my C++ program. Here is my code:

```
boost::filesystem::path dir("./results");
if (!boost::filesystem::exists(dir)) {
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(dir);
}
```

```
boost::filesystem::create_directory: Illegal byte sequence [system:92]: "@��l"
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. The path I'm using is correct, and I'm running the program on M1 Mac. What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

I've tried changing the path to a shorter one, but it didn't help.
I've also tried using boost::filesystem::path::codecvt() to convert the path, but it didn't work either.

path has the _M_p and _M_local_buf. These values are _M_p:"./results/"
_M_local_buf:"./results/\0o\U00000001".

Comment: "Illegal byte sequence" is a dead giveaway that the path is not, in fact, correct. How is `path` constructed and what does it actually contain?

Comment: The most common gotcha behind such an error is forgetting the difference between ascii and utf-8, in my experience. You need to take a good look at path, first.

Comment: In this case, cout the path will result in ". /results".
So, if I type the full path in solid type, I get the exact same error. I use codecvt so I think path is utf-8, but it's happen

Comment: As an aside, the result of `exists` will be valid for about half a nanosecond. Any other program or thread can add or remove files all the time. Calling `create_directory` on an existing directory is not an error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share what does `dir` actually contain - along with its hexadecimal dump if possible.

Comment: @curiim cout is not a reliable representation of message contents. use a debugger instead.